# I encounter a 401 unauthorized in my JMeter scripts response each time when I try to send an xas-request to a Mendix application

Tags: jmeter, fiddler, mendix

I have little experience in using JMeter, so my sincere apologies if I'm missing something totally obvious here.

However, I get a 401 each time I try to make an HTTP Request in which a query is send to the server, the request looks as follows:

```
{"action":"retrieve_by_query","params": {"queryId":"DkWjkFD27UKYSz9ytWW5ew","constraint":"","context":"37154696925809628","options":{"sort":[["DCM.TaskInstance_TaskCategoryInstance/DCM.TaskCategoryInstance/DCM.TaskCategoryInstance_TaskCategory/DCM.TaskCategory/OrderNumber","desc"],["HasMessages","desc"]],"offset":0,"amount":100}},"profiledata":{"1584961703745-131":51,"1584961703743-130":58,"1584961703774-133":106,"1584961703773-132":221}}
```

And the response data is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-store
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3769bc7afaf737a4a03d956ebdfc5742c39a3f6232952e26cf18d2da49b83c1e;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=****-t.****-ta.p.azurewebsites.net
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 14:13:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I already tried to make the request message correspond with the stream that I checked with Fiddler, however this didn't bring me much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol used to communicate between the client and server in a Mendix app is quite complicated because the server-side is stateless. Before sending your request to the server, you need to make sure the client (JMeter in this case) is authenticated. So to build a successful JMeter script, you would have to record and replay the whole sequence of communication, from authentication to the query you want to check. This approach is quite time-consuming.

The official position here is that this type of testing should be done using a selenium based solution.

The documentation referenced in the earlier answer details the authentication for API's exposed by the Mendix platform, not the authentication between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Authentication](https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/apidocs/authentication) chapter of Mendix documentation you should be sending `Mendix-Username` and `Mendix-ApiKey` [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so make sure to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to your Test Plan and configure it to send the aforementioned headers.

Comment: So far I have been able to successfully automate the Login-process, but any xas-requests fail because of authorization failures. I will try and send all of the authorization tokens with each request and see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Well... that didn't help unfortunately.